# SimpleXMLElement - get an attribute of a node

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a SimpleXMLObject `$node`, which contains an array 'data' which i have to retrieve, but i don't know how. i've with `$node['data']` but it doesn't work. any help?

Maybe it's simple but i don't know how to do it quickly..

**Edit:** sample code

```
foreach ($xmlObject->children() as $node) {
    if($node->getName() == 'URL_web_images'){

        // here i have a $node that contains an array named 'URL_web_image', how to access to it?

    }
}
```

Comment: @jugnu: http://pastie.org/3987941

Answer (score 1):

SimpleXML is a class and `$node` seems to be its instance. You can't access properties like arrays in php. you have to use `$obj->property`.

So try this:

```
echo $node->data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print_r(json_decode($node));
$node_json = json_decode($node);
echo $node_json['data'];
```

Comment: Why does he/she need it when he can directly access its value?

Comment: This is another way to get data through this ....... there is no hard and fast rule @PLB

Comment: @PLB this array contains url fro files that i have to download through a functions. i have to retrieve it. Is there another way?

Comment: Sure, it is, but I don't see any reason why you should write extra lines when they are not needed.

Comment: @lukelukes let's see what's the output. `echo '<pre>';var_dump($node);echo'</pre>';` and update question, please.

Comment: @PLB well so tell me ho to access it please!

Comment: @lukelukes take a look on my answer.

Comment: Hey @PLB what are you trying to achieve if you think your answer is perfect then why argue with us